# Bootstrap Date Picker XPages

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

I am trying to add a date picker to my site that has been "bootstraped". I am not using the DoJo picker or the native picker because of aesthetics. Here are the components that I am currently using:

1. http://bootstrap4xpages.openntf.org/ => installed and working perfectly
2. bootstrap date picker: http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/?markup=input&format=dd.mm.yyyy&weekStart=&startDate=&endDate=&startView=0&minViewMode=0&todayBtn=false&language=en&orientation=auto&multidate=&multidateSeparator=&keyboardNavigation=on&forceParse=on#sandbox => This was installed by coping the .js and .css files into the database.
3. I have read through (and understood I think) Marky's blog entry: http://xomino.com/2012/01/26/using-jquery-selectors-in-xpages/

My problem is that no matter what I do I cannot get jQuery to add the .datepicker element to my field. I have tried both Marky's function, using a class name as the selector and just entering it directly. Does anybody have an idea what I am doing wrong?

Thank you in advance
Ursus

PS: I would like to add that this is the first time I am using jQuery and bootstrap so be easy on me :o)

Here is the code:

=================== xPage =================

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex" xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">
    <xp:this.resources>
        <xp:script src="/bootstrap-datepicker.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
        <xp:styleSheet href="/datepicker3.css"></xp:styleSheet>
        <xp:script src="/jsTestBootstrap.js" clientSide="true"></xp:script>
    </xp:this.resources>
    <xp:panel
        style="margin-left:10.0px;margin-right:10.0px;margin-top:10.0px;margin-bottom:10.0px">
        <xp:div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <xp:label value="Select a date" id="label1" for="inputText1"></xp:label>
                    <xp:inputText id="inputText1" styleClass="jqDateField">
                    </xp:inputText>
                </div>
            </div>
        </xp:div>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

===================== and here my clientSide code to select the field ==============

```
$("#view\\:_id1\\:inputText1").datepicker({
    format: "dd.mm.yyyy"
});
```

====================== end =========================================================

Comment: Try using the X$ function from this post: http://xomino.com/2012/03/09/x-reference-examples/  It works very well so your code would look like x$(“#{id:inputText1}”).datepicker({format: "dd.mm.yyyy"});

Comment: Have you tried a class selector? $(".jqDateField") - use a classSelector and save yourself some heartache

One other thing you could try and look at it the z-index of the date picker - is it being created and not visible? I had that issue with jQueryUI date picker - was working but not visible. Use firebug to see if the selector works.

Comment: @MarkyRoden: yes, I tried the class selector but it still didn't work. The field is being created and is visible! Spent all afternoon with firebug :o) I even had a work colleague look at it who does a lot of bootstrap and AngularJS (spelling?) - he couldn't find my error either

Comment: @SteveZavocki: I have tried that numerous times - I added Marks code in a jsLibrary then added your code (the " seemed to get a mixed up - this is what I am using: x$("#{id:inputText1}").datepicker({format: "dd.mm.yyyy"});) - I then get the following error in the console: Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ##{id\:inputText1}

Comment: Here is an actual code example that works: x$("#{id:inputHidden1}").val(formattedDate); Perhaps the formatting is set in a different way, I am using datepick.js, and I set the formatting in the panel and it works correctly.

Comment: As an alternative, you could try using moment.js to format the date. (must download and add libary) Here is an example:  var formattedDate = new Date(dates);
    formattedDate = moment(formattedDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY');

Comment: Ursus - the x$ function is for SSJS - if you are using it in client side JavaScript you will get the error reported. Will it work with a non-XPages field - let's see if it is and XPage problem or date picker problem :)

Comment: sometimes jQuery doesn't load due to dojo AMD conflict.  Are you sure jQuery is ready and working?

Comment: The Bootstrap4XPages.com site contains a working demo the eternicode date picker. It also uses the Bootstrap4XPages plugin. You can view the demo, download the demo db or view the source on Github.com. BTW: the plugin also contains the x$ function out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you very much for all the input. Mark reached out to me and we solved the problem using TeamViewer. There where multiple errors. Here goes:

1. I created a client side JavaScript library to hold the x$ code from Mark - this was the first problem -> I needed to include it as a  `< script >`  block
2. I am using jSignature (http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=934) to allow users to sign the document -> when adding jSignature I added jQuery 1.8.1 - Bootstrap4XPages installs jQuery 1.8.2 -> 2 x jQuery was a problem for the selector (funnily enough jSignature still worked).

So, it's now working with all your help. Thank you very much :o)

Have a good day
Ursus

Answer (score 2):

See my blog post, http://elstarit.nl/?p=118.
There I use different one, but I like it a lot because it has a date picker and time picker in one.
But back to your JQuery problem. Do you know which version of JQuery is needed? 
Last week I banged my head against the wall, because in Bootstrap4XPages JQuery 1.8.x is loaded and my plugin required a newer version.
After switching of Bootstrap4XPages and loaded JQuery by myself the problem was fixed.

Comment: Thank you for you input Frank - my problem is that I cannot select the DOM element using jQuery (i.e. Mark's x$ function) - your code is very similar in that it uses the x$ function - which isn't working for me :o(